# Scraping contents of web that has specific url

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I wanna get the titles and urls that has specific doc links. so, from the codes below, I wanna get informations : the Titles, and http://linkWeb.com that has specific url download .pdf http://link.pdf

Here's the html page :

```
<div class="title-download">
<div id="01divTitle" class="title">
    <h3>
        <a id="01Title" onmousedown="" href="http://linkWeb.com">Titles</a>
        <span id="01LbCitation" class="citation">(<a id="01Citation" href="http://citation.com">Citations</a>)</span></h3>
</div>
<div id="01downloadDiv" class="download">
    <a id="01_downloadIcon" title="http://link.pdf" onmousedown="" target=""><img id="ctl01_icon" class="small-icon";" /></a>
</div>
```

and here's the code, but it returns blank result :

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
set_time_limit(0);
$url  ='http://example.com';
$html = file_get_html($url) or die ('invalid url');

foreach($html->find('span[class=citation]') as $link){
    foreach($link->parent()->parent()->find('.download a') as $link2){  //I confused with the code in this line
       if(strtolower(substr($link2->title, strrpos($link2->title, '.'))) === '.pdf') {
           $link = $link->prev_sibling();
           echo $link->plaintext.'<br>';
           echo $link->href.'<br>';
       echo $link2->title.'<br>'; 
       }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Wait, `http://link.pdf`? How does that work? Or is that just a dummy URL instead of publishing the actual site name?

Comment: @Matchu oh, I am sorry. Typo in the html page. I edited it = `title"http://link.pdf"` <- in the class download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `$link` is the citation span, `$link->parent()->parent()` returns the `div` with ID `01divTitle`. And, since that `div` is a *sibling* of the `.download` element you're looking for rather than a parent, `$link->parent()->parent()->find('.download a')` returns no results.

Perhaps `$link->parent()->parent()->parent()->find('.download a')` would work better. There may be other issues, but that's definitely one of them.